# Linking tesseract and opencv in Visual Studio 2013 on x64 bit machine

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, tesseract

I'm trying to run a program based on **tesseract** and **opencv** on **Visual Studio 2013**. I have a **x64 bit machine** and the problem is when I run it under Win32 I got only opencv linking errors, however under x64 I got tesseract linking errors.

Here are some errors screenshots :

***Tesseract Errors :***

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pixDestroy
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pixReadTesseract
error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

***Opencv Errors :***

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvLoadImage  
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvCreateImage    
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvSaveImage  
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvReleaseImage   
error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Thank you guys :-)

Comment: "I run it under Win32" -- how can you run it when you can't link it? Do you mean when you try to compile the program for the given platform? Looks like you have 32bit build of tesseract and 64bit build of opencv, and trying to use them both in the same program. That's obviously not going to work.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, because I searched about tesseract .dll files for x64 platform but I didn't find anything !

Comment: If you want to stick with OpenCV 3.1 (since the standard distro package doesn't seem to contain 32bit binaries), then you have to go and build one of the libraries yourself. IIRC the older versions still had them.

Comment: Actually maybe this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/opencv3.1/) will do. Just download it and the redist. They're really just zipfiles and you can dig out the relevant bits manually, without even needing nuget.

Comment: Million thanks guys for your help, I merged into opencv 32 bits and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that you have 32bit build of Tesseract and 64bit build of OpenCV, and trying to use them both in the same program. That will not work -- you either need all 64bit libraries for a 64bit application, or all 32bit libraries for a 32bit application.

If you want to stick with OpenCV 3.1 (since the standard distribution package doesn't seem to contain 32bit binaries), then you have to go and build one of the libraries yourself. The older versions still had them.

Another option is to download [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/opencv3.1/) along with the associated redistributables package. Since the files are just ZIP files with a different extension, it is possible to extract all the headers, import libraries and DLLs manually.